# Open all external links in new window

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I am using below code to covert all links pass through a php script - Now i want these links to pop open in a new window

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {  
$("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
 var value = $(this).attr('href');
 $(this).attr('href','<url>/pqr.php?'+value);
});
```

});

Links are opening in same window? How to get them opened in a new window.

Comment: ANd what is the problem?

Comment: links are opening in same window now... I want them to open in a new window

Comment: Add them attribute `target="_blank"`

Comment: this snippet converts external link to pass through pgr.php script i want this to open in new window

Comment: You already told that.

Comment: do you want them to open in a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding this:

```
$(this).attr("target","_blank");
```

EDIT: integrated like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href','<url>/pqr.php?'+value);
        $(this).attr("target","_blank");
    });
});
```

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bontp6jk/

Comment: Working now!! refreshed the cache !! Thanks Felk

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").attr("target","_blank");

});
```

Comment: how about manually adding the target _blank in your html(or php) file